# android data binding MaterialBetterSpinner inside recyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio

do someone have a sample of this?
or can tell how the adaptor have to look like?
this is adaptor inside adaptor(the adaptor to inflate the recyclerView, and the adaptor to inflate the MaterialBetterSpinner layout that inside each item of the recyclerView)
thanx!

Comment: or even somthing simple than this, someone knows how to add a spinner inside recyclerView without data binding?

Comment: you need to have a populated spinner inisde each row of recyclerview ,am i right??

Comment: yes that exactly what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give u some idea...

```
public class Yearly_day_type_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Yearly_day_type_adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Year_Day_Type_Model> moviesList;
    private Context context;
    TextView txt;
    int pos;
    private List<String> monthList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> monthAdapter;  

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public Spinner spinner_left_yearly; 
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            spinner_left_yearly = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_left_yearly);

        }
    }


    public Yearly_day_type_adapter(Context context,List<Year_Day_Type_Model> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.yearly_day_type, parent, false);



        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        populateSpinner();
        holder.spinner_left_yearly.setAdapter(monthAdapter);
        holder.spinner_left_yearly.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(moviesList.get(position).getMonPos()));
        holder.spinner_left_yearly.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                moviesList.get(position).setMonPos(String.valueOf(pos));
                MultipleSelectionActivity.setYearlyDayTypeMonth(position,pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }


        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return moviesList.size();

    }
    public void populateSpinner() {
        monthList = new ArrayList<>();
        monthList.add("Januvary");
        monthList.add("Februvary");
        monthList.add("March");
        monthList.add("April");
        monthList.add("May");
        monthList.add("June");
        monthList.add("July");
        monthList.add("August");
        monthList.add("September");
        monthList.add("October");
        monthList.add("Novemebr");
        monthList.add("December");
        monthAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, monthList);
        monthAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }
```